# Python exercise with url and string counting

Tags: python

i'm having a little problem with an exercise i have to do : 
Basically the assignment is to open an url, convert it into a given format, and count the number of occurrences of given strings in the text.

```
import urllib2 as ul 

def word_counting(url, code, words):
    page = ul.urlopen(url)
    text = page.read()
    decoded = ext.decode(code)
    result = {}

    for word in words:
        count = decoded.count(word)
        counted = str(word) + ":" + " " + str(count)
        result.append(counted)

    return finale
```

The result i should get is like " word1: x, word2: y, word3: z " with x,y,z being the number of occurrences. But it seems that i only get ONE number, when i try to run the test program i get as result only like 9 for the first occurrences, 14 for the second list, 5 for the third, missing the other occurrences and the whole counted value.
What am i doing wrong? Thanks in advance

Comment: You might want to look at the Counter dict: http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter

Answer (score 1):

You're not appending to the dictionary correctly.

The correct way is `result[key] = value`.

So for your loop it would be

```
for word in words:
  count = decoded.count(word)
  result[word] = str(count)
```

An example without decode but using `.count()`

```
words = ['apple', 'apple', 'pear', 'banana']
result= {}
  for word in words:
    count = words.count(word)
    result[word] = count

>>> result
>>> {'pear': 1, 'apple': 2, 'banana': 1}
```

Answer (score 1):

Or you can use Collections.Counter :

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> words = ['apple', 'apple', 'pear', 'banana']
>>> Counter(words)
Counter({'apple': 2, 'pear': 1, 'banana': 1})
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget about list and dictionary comprehensions. They can be quite efficient on larger sets of data (especially if you are analysing a large web-page in your example). At the end of the day, if your data set is small, one could argue that the dict comprehension syntax is cleaner/more pythonic etc.

So in this case I would use something like:

```
result = {word : decoded.count(word) for word in words}
```